# modify object based on values in array

Tags: javascript

I want to modify values in an object if its keys exist in an array,

maybe some combination of Object.keys or indexOf().

so basically I have an object that looks like this

```
{
  '9': true,
  '10': false,
  '11': true,
  '12': true,
  '13': true,
  '14': true,
  '15': true,
  '16': true,
  '17': true,
  '18': true,
  '19': true,
}
```

and an array that may look like this;

```
['10','15','18']
```

and I want to end up with this;

```
{
  '9': true,
  '10': true,
  '11': true,
  '12': true,
  '13': true,
  '14': true,
  '15': false,
  '16': true,
  '17': true,
  '18': false,
  '19': true,
}
```

so essentially if a key exists in the array, change its boolean value to false.

Comment: The last phrase contradicts with what you do for key '10'

Comment: the boolean is not whether the key exists in the array, sorry I know it's not the best method.

Comment: It seems you want to *toggle* the boolean value for a given key if it exists, right?

Comment: yes, but i want to end up with false in if exist

Comment: Well, '10' exists, and you set it to `true`. Please explain.

Comment: sorry, typo!! lol

Comment: So what should it be? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use your values as keys in the input array:

```
const x = {
    '9': true,
    '10': false,
    '11': true,
    '12': true,
    '13': true,
    '14': true,
    '15': true,
    '16': true,
    '17': true,
    '18': true,
    '19': true,
}

['10','15','18'].forEach((val) => {
    if(x.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
        x[val] = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array with the keys and check if the property exists and then change the value to `false`.

```js
var object = { 9: true, 10: false, 11: true, 12: true, 13: true, 14: true, 15: true, 16: true, 17: true, 18: true, 19: true },
    keys = ['10', '15', '18'];
  
keys.forEach(k => k in object && (object[k] = false));

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this one is really close, however, my objects keys are strings of numbers, I think that's causing a problem, when I try your object it works fine.

Comment: all keys of objects are strings, even if they are numbers in an object literal.